# Extract pattern from string, with special characters, using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex

I am trying to use a regex in VB.NET - the language probably shouldn't matter though - I am trying to extract something reasonable out of a very large file name, "`\\path\path\path.path.path\path\some_more_stuff_from a name.item_123_456.html`"

I would like to extract, from that whole mess, the "`item_123_456`"

It seems to make sense that I can get everything before a pattern like ".html" , and from it, everything after the last dot ?

I have tried to get at least the last part (the entire string before .html) and I still get no matches:

```
Dim matches As MatchCollection
Dim regexStuff As New Regex(".*\\.html")
matches = regexStuff.Matches(strINeed)
Dim successfulMatch As Match
For Each successfulMatch In matches
  strFound = successfulMatch.Value
Next
```

The match I experimented with, hoping I might even get everything between a dot and an `.html`: `Regex("\\..*\\.html")` returned Nothing as well.

I just can't get regular expressions to work...

Comment: This question raises questions. What if there is no dot anywhere before the `.html`? And what if its `\\path\path.path\somejunk.html` with no apparent item number?

Comment: @sln: You have a point - I am trying to extract something that some users can recognize, from what they are likely to use for some type of identifiers - and if the search fails, will just use something like "file #1" - and then try to make it more fool-proof as I get more information or am able to enforce what the identifiers can be.

Comment: I wouldn't fret about it. It is what it is. There are some upvotes given without the correct/most helpfull mark, and you should not feel pressure to do so. It's not a race to the fastest/first answer, more like a quest for knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.*\.(.*?)\.html
```

This finds as many characters as possible `.*` until it comes to ( a dot followed by as few characters as possible followed by a dot html ) (`\.(.*?)\.html`)

It places the stuff between the dot html and the dot preceding the dot html into a capturing group, which should be in $1. If you need the vb.net code for that I can likely get that as well, but your code looked okay

Your vb code should look something like this:

```
Dim matches As MatchCollection
Dim regexStuff As New Regex(".*\.(.*?)\.html")
matches = regexStuff.Matches(strINeed)
strFound = matches.Item(0).Groups(1).Value.ToString
```

Answer (score 1):

It could probably be generalized into this

```
[^.\\]+\.html
```

*Edit*: or, initial dot required

```
\.[^.\\]+\.html
```

Comment: This solution won't span paths.